# How do I put the following image as flutter_native_splash

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwuVT.png)

How do I put the following image as flutter_native_splash I tried and it didn't ..

Comment: Uh, by following the instructions?  It's pretty well documented.  Where did you get stuck?